# How to refer to specific item in JSON android?

Tags: android, json, listview

I'm following a tutorial on JSON in android. I've managed to output JSON from the file into `ListView`. However, I don't quite understand how referring to specific item works.
Here is json file:

```
    {
  "contacts": [
    {
      "id": "c200",
      "name": "Ravi Tamada",
      "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
      "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
      "gender" : "male",
      "phone": {
        "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
        "home": "00 000000",
        "office": "00 000000"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "c201",
      "name": "Figaro",
      "email": "figaro@gmail.com",
      "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
      "gender" : "male",
      "phone": {
        "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
        "home": "00 000000",
        "office": "00 000000"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "c202",
      "name": "Johnny Depp",
      "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
      "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
      "gender" : "female",
      "phone": {
        "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
        "home": "00 000000",
        "office": "00 000000"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

First thing: How can I output items for example with "gender = male" only?
Second thing: Whenever I press for example on Ravi Tamada in my `ListView`, how can I make it load up it's mobile only? in other words, how can I set the link between the item I press and the information that should be displayed, while taking into account its relation to the pressed item?

This is how I retrive items from json:

```
 switch (view.getId()){

            case R.id.button1:
                loadmyjson();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);

                    JSONArray letters = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts");
                    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject first = letters.getJSONObject(i);
                        String gender = first.getString("gender");
                        Log.e("and that means", " " + gender);

                        if (first.getString("name") == "Figaro"){
                            where.add(gender);


                        }

                         }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.e("and that means", " " + where);

                break;

        }
```

The problem is that this if statement is always false.

Comment: First thing: you should create an object with the same structure of that Json. Then you just have to iterate the list and save the ones with the attribute "gender" = "male". Second thing: you have to create a callback between your adapter and your activity/fragment. And create a onClickListener and set it to each itemView inside your ViewHolder passing as parameter the position or the item itself you clicked on.

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain how to iterate it? I've tried with if statement, but it's always false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead `first.getString("name") == "Figaro"` try `first.getString("name").equals("Figaro")`

Comment: Thanks, that put end to all my issues